# Validate Omniture document.write()'s are efficient and non-stacking

Tags: report, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics, document.write

I want to be certain that the *omniture* calls for `document.write()`'s are nullified/cleared from the DOM for each new call.

### Criteria:

1. I want to see what gets written to the DOM with a Adobe Omniture `call(s.t() call)` for example
2. I want to make sure that the DOM writes are cleared/nullified out before adding each new call
3. How to prove the DOM value is nullified/cleared.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about this part of the on-page code:

```
/************* DO NOT ALTER ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE ! **************/ 
var s_code=s.t();if(s_code)document.write(s_code)//--></script>
```

Adobe Analytics (Omniture) tracking makes its request to the collection server by creating an image object. Modern browsers make the request when you set the `imageObject.src` attribute with the URL. The reason `document.write()` is used is to accommodate if the request is not made from simply setting a value to `imageObject.src`.

Basically, the AA code checks if the `imageObject.src` successfully loaded the returned image. If so, `s.t()` returns an empty string. If not, `s.t()` returns a full `img` tag, which gets added to DOM from the `document.write()`.

This `document.write()` fallback is meant to accommodate older browsers. And by "older" I mean IE4 old.  If you do not care about tracking browsers that old (hint: nobody does), you can just cut all of the "trigger" code down to the single `s.t()` call (no need to even assign to `s_code`).

So to answer your question, nothing is actually document written to the DOM unless you are on an ancient browser.  But in the case that you *are* on an ancient browser.. no, there is no code that removes previous stuff appended. Which brings me to...

..What are you *really* asking?  IOW, *why* are you trying to find out / make certain that it is removed?  I suspect what you may *really* be asking is something along the lines of wanting to make sure previously set AA variables do not get popped on subsequent requests.  Which is a fair thing to ask, but that doesn't really have anything to do with the request itself.  But you will need to clarify that point.